# Meaning / interpretation of weird Tom & Jerry scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, analysis, tom-and-jerry, tom-and-jerry-the-fast-n-the-furry

In [this scene](https://youtu.be/J-v5f0s6bvc) from *Tom and Jerry: The Fast and the Furry* we see some weird stuff.

Below a few screenshots to help locate it:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I can't understand what's happening in this scene. How to interpret this scene?

Comment: It's riffing on the well-worn theme of "conspiracy theories" that some secret organisation is somehow actually "in charge of everything". [Usually the Illuminati, Freemsasons, or space aliens, amongst the most common]

Comment: "does anybody know the episode's name/number by the way?" is off topic

Comment: It's [Tom and Jerry: The Fast and the Furry (2005)](https://animationscreencaps.com/tom-jerry-fast-furry-2005/8/)

Comment: @Napoleon Wilson: In original question OP wasn't aware of the movie/episode to which given pictures belong to.

Comment: @Rahul I know. Then someone edited it in, so the question became obsolete (as it would also be off-topic if that was the main question).

Comment: @NapoleonWilson: I edited it to make the identification part secondary due to which it attracted close votes.

Comment: @Rahul Sure you did. But it's not necessary anymore now, since someone found it anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### They're satirizing Hollywood and Hollywood producers by depicting them as a bizarre, Freemason-like cult that takes its orders from the devil.

In the [scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dHMu0jnass), a Hollywood producer (in the blue suit) is rejecting the idea of letting animals be contestants on his TV game show. As he is rejecting Tom and Jerry's petition, an object on his desk that closely resembles a Freemason symbol rings like a telephone and the producer and his assistant don hats similar to the pyramid/eye Freemason symbol and get on their knees to answer a call from "the President of Hollywood." When the President of Hollywood's image materializes inside a strange cylinder-like aparatus, he has the outline of the devil.

The scene is poking fun at Hollywood in general and producers specifically by basically saying that they are all part of some kind of unholy, occultist cabal and they take their orders directly from the devil. This is also possibly intended to poke fun at people who criticize Hollywood productions on religious grounds, and conspiracy theorists who hypothecize that Freemasons are an all-powerful group with murky, sinister motivations.

Comment: Any idea why the movie's producers would do that in a movie whose target audience is primarily children?

Comment: Lots of “kid’s movies” have jokes aimed at parents to make them a more attractive option for parents, who will have to sit through them. These jokes are not always well-conceived. For example, the live action Cat in the Hat has a boner joke in it. The bad guy in Shrek is named “Farquad,” which quite intentionally sounds like “f*ck wad.” This scene is an example of potentially controversial adult humor in a kid movie.